# Figure problems: Add a line + two extra numbers in a row

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows

I have two problems with my figure. My figure look like this:

[image]

Instead of one number, I would like to have three numbers in a row (see the red circle). I have also tried to add a arrows down from the circle: "Subtractive disconfirmation" and "Satisfy", as shown in by red in the figure below:

[image]

My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={%
                ,ellipse
                ,minimum width=4.5cm
                ,minimum height=1.5cm
                ,draw
                ,align=center
            }}
            ,every arrow/.append style={-LaTeX, >=LaTeX}
            ,row sep=2cm
            ,column sep=2cm
            ]
            Mindset 

            \arrow{dr}[swap]{37,2}
            \arrow{drr}{39,2}
            &[-4cm] & \\
            & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Subtractive\\ disconfirmation\end{tabular} \arrow{r}{40,4} & Satisfy\\
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}General\\ behaviour\end{tabular}
            \arrow{ur}{17,2}
            \arrow{urr}[swap]{50,1}
            & &
        \end{tikzcd}        
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={%
                ,ellipse
                ,minimum width=4.5cm
                ,minimum height=1.5cm
                ,draw
                ,align=center
            }}
            ,every arrow/.append style={-LaTeX, >=LaTeX}
            ,row sep=2cm
            ,column sep=2cm,
            execute at end picture={
              \draw[red]
                (satisfy.south) --
                ++(0pt,-5cm)
                node[below,text=black,font=\scriptsize] {$\begin{array}{c} 39,2 \\ 12,6 \\ 3,35\end{array}$};
              \draw[red]
                (subtractive.south) --
                ++(0pt,-5cm)
                node[below,text=black,font=\scriptsize] {$\begin{array}{c} 39,2 \\ 12,6 \\ 3,35\end{array}$};
            }
            ]
            Mindset 

            \arrow{dr}[swap]{37,2}
            \arrow{drr}{\begin{array}{c} 39,2 \\ 12,6 \\ 3,35\end{array}}
            &[-4cm] & \\
            & |[alias=subtractive]|\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Subtractive\\ disconfirmation\end{tabular} \arrow{r}{40,4} & |[alias=satisfy]|Satisfy\\
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}General\\ behaviour\end{tabular}
            \arrow{ur}{17,2}
            \arrow{urr}[swap]{50,1}
            & &
        \end{tikzcd}        
\end{document}
```

### Explanation

1. To have a multirow label, I simply used an `array`.
2. To draw the arrows, I used the `alias` key to name the "Satisfy" and "Subtractive" nodes and used `execute at end picture` to `\draw` the lines with two nodes at the end having the desired text.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation - that was exactly what I needed. I have one last question. Is it possible to make the two draws with an "arrow" pointed  up to the circle?

Comment: @A.F. You're welcome. Regarding the arrow, replace `\draw[red]` with `\draw[red,<-,>=latex]`.

Comment: Thank you again Gonzalo. If I would like the three numbers to be left align? Is that possible?

Comment: @A.F. Use a `l` in the format specification for the `array`: `\begin{array}{l} ... \end{array}`.

Comment: It say illegal character. I have also tried \begin{flushleft} \end{flushleft}

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It works now. :-) Thank you!

Comment: If I would like to change the size between numbers, I just change linespace?

Comment: @A.F. What do you mean with "size" between numbers?

Comment: I mean the space between the numbers. If I would like these to be more compressed (i.e. setspace). Furthermore, if I would like to change the fonttype from italic to normal, how would I do that (is there a easy way?)?

Comment: @A.F. Use `\\[-10pt]` to decrease the vertical space inside the `array` (using positive values you can increase the distance). Change the fonttype where exactly? I think there are too many questions already here. Consider opening a fresh new question.

Answer (score 1):

With help of `stackengine˙ it is easy:
[image]
Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={%
                ,ellipse
                ,minimum width=4.5cm
                ,minimum height=1.5cm
                ,draw
                ,align=center
            }}
            ,every arrow/.append style={-LaTeX, >=LaTeX}
            ,row sep=2cm
            ,column sep=2cm
            ]
            Mindset

            \arrow{dr}[swap]{\Shortstack[c]{37,2 BBB CCC}}%<---
            \arrow{drr}{39,2}
            &[-4cm] & \\
            & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Subtractive\\ disconfirmation\end{tabular} \arrow{r}{40,4} & Satisfy\\
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}General\\ behaviour\end{tabular}
            \arrow{ur}{17,2}
            \arrow{urr}[swap]{50,1}
            & &
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```